# IFormFile gets disposed while doing async operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, async-await

I have a ASP.Net Core 2.0 webapi code that looks like following

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISampleRepository _sampleRepository = new SampleRepository();

    [HttpPost("{id}")]
    public async void Post([FromRoute]int id, IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, [FromForm] NotifyViewModel model)
    {
        // get data from DB using async
        var dbData = await _sampleRepository.GetAsync(id);

        //check if email alert is enabled 
        if(dbData.IsEmailEnabled)
        {
            //create MailMessage
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage() { 
                //options here 
                };

            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(formFile.OpenReadStream(), formFile.FileName, formFile.ContentType));
            }

            // send email
            _emailHelper.SendEmail(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}

public class SampleRepository 
{
    public async Task<SampleData> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        //get data using Dapper & return
        var result = await con.QuerySingleAsync<SampleData>(sql, new {id = id}, null, null, CommandType.Text);

        return result;
    }
}
```

When I post data to this endpoint I get exception saying `'Cannot access disposed object.'` (Refer screenshot)

[image]

However when I make DB operation synchronous by doing following code changes, somehow it works without any error.

```
// Removed
// var dbData = await _sampleRepository.GetAsync(id);

// Newly added. Made DB operations synchronous
var dbData = _sampleRepository.GetAsync(id).Result;
```

Can someone please help me understand this behavior? Why HTTP posted files gets disposed when async operation is involved?

Comment: What is the type of `MailMessage`? Also in your listing the variable is `message` but in the screenshot it is `mailMessage`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I missed that while writing dummy code for SO post. I am using <code>MailMessage</code> from namespace <code>System.Net.Mail</code>

Comment: What do you Post that implements `IFormFile`?

Comment: Keeping `await` in place, can you print out `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` before and after going to db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your method is `async void` it immediately returns as soon as it hits the first `await`. By the time the code accesses request data, the request has already ended.

Change the signature of `Post` from `async void Post` to `async Task Post` as `async Task` is the asynchronous analogue of the synchronous `void`.

Comment: FWIW, though, `void`/`Task` will result in a 200 status code with no content body *always*. If this is an API endpoint, you should explicitly return `NoContent()` if that's what it should in fact do. If this is an MVC action (i.e. you're posting from a browser tab), then you should always returning some HTML document, or you're going to strand the user on a blank page. In general, there's very little reason to have any action method return anything but `IActionResult`/`Task<IActionResult>`.